# Mod rewrite issue make a dot obligated

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried to create a Mod Rewrite .htaccess script(? can you call it script?)

And I have two lines that are interfering with each other.
The rules are:

```
rewriterule ^(.*).tcl index.php?SetTravelCode=$1
```

And :

```
rewriterule ^status_(.*)_(.*).xml$ ?booking_status=$1&set_language=$2
```

When I call upon :

mydomain.com/status_<<**SOME DYNAMIC STUFF**>>_en.xml

The request SHOULD go to:

*mydomain.com/?booking_status=728937iwyeiytcl23973&set_language=en*

But instead forwards the request to:

*mydomain.com/?SetTravelCode=728937iwyeiytcl23973*

Which is incorrect..

I DO know why. But not how to change this.
Because the dynamic token as set contains tcl.
But a DOT has should be required to forward to

*mydomain.com?SetTravelCode=728937iwyeiytcl23973*

I hope that anyone could tell me how to make the dot obligated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.tcl$ index.php?SetTravelCode=$1
```

Note the `\.`

`.` in regex matches *any* character. In order to match a literal `.` you need to escape it with `\`

Comment: Correct. I would also suggest OP to use `^(.*)\.tcl$` if the code will always end with `.tcl`.